# Taking date and time of last 5 days

Tags: bash, date

I know that I can take date and time of yesterday by writing

```
dt=`date +"%d-%m-%Y" -d "-1 day"`
```

Similarly I want to find -2 day, -3 day and so on. When I put this command in loop, and write it as

```
dt=`date +"%d-%m-%Y" -d "-$i day"`
```

it didn't worked. Am I wrong somewhere or there is some another way to do such stuff.

Comment: It worked for me: `for i in {1..4}; do echo `date +"%d-%m-%Y" -d "-$i day"`; done` prints: 17-02-2016 16-02-2016 15-02-2016 14-02-2016

Comment: @AvihooMamka +1 though the [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) always irks me.